# Type mismatch when processing a stream with maxBy()

Tags: java

I'm writing a code to handle Mountain Huts in different municipalities in different provinces. I'm trying to compute the maximum number of beds available in a single mountain hut per altitude range. If the altitude of the mountain hut is not available, i'll use the
altitude of its municipality.
I would like my method to return a `Map<String, Optional<Integer>>` but i'm getting a `Map <String , Optional<MountainHut>>` . Now i am aware of the fact that the Optional i am getting is actually the one who has the maximum bed number but i am struggling to get the right data type.

```
public Map<String, Optional<Integer>> maximumBedsNumberPerAltitudeRange()
{
    return this.getMountainHuts().stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy((MountainHut mountainHut) ->
                this.getAltitudeRange(
                    mountainHut.getAltitude().orElse(mountainHut.getMunicipality().getAltitude())
                ),
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(MountainHut::getBedsNumber))
            )
        );
}
```

For completeness i'll post also the getAltitudeRange method, the other 
methods are just getters.

```
public String getAltitudeRange(Integer altitude) {
    Range r = ranges.stream()
        .filter((x) -> altitude>= x.getMin() || altitude <= x.getMax())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(new Range(0,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    ranges.stream().close();
    if(r.getMax() == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        return (0 +" - "+ "INF");
    }
    return (r.getMin() + " - " + r.getMax());
}
```

Altitude is an Optional attribute of the class MountainHut

As expected the error message is the following:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map> to 
 Map>

Comment: The number of beds present in the considered Mountain Hut

Comment: You aren't transforming MountainHut into Integer. Why would you expect it to return Integer?

Comment: @Eran It's an Integer

Comment: @glee8e that's exactly what i'm trying to figure out, i don't get to trasform it to the desired type (Integer).

Comment: @Eran yes i am, the Optional return type is linked to the maxBy method

Answer (score 1):

`maxBy` doesn't transform, it just compare. Your extracting the key (i.e. bed number) is implementation detail of your `Comparator` which `maxBy` has no knowledge of.

You are actually very close though. You just need to add an intermediate step between groupingBy and maxBy.

```
public Map<String, Optional<Integer>> maximumBedsNumberPerAltitudeRange()
{
    return this.getMountainHuts().stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy((MountainHut mountainHut) ->
                this.getAltitudeRange(
                    mountainHut.getAltitude().orElse(mountainHut.getMunicipality().getAltitude())
                ),
                Collectors.mapping(MountainHut::getBedsNumber, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            )
        );
}
```

PS: In stream heavy classes you can add an `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*` to get rid of boilerplate.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just have one more doubt , why do yoi specify naturalOrder inside maxBy insted of the key to be considered as the ordering key?

Comment: Because `maxBy` is the downstream collector of that `mapping` collector, which has already done the job of extracting the key. In other words, the input of `maxBy` is already changed to bed number. It is not operating on a stream of `MountainHut`s but a stream of `Integer` (which is bed number)